# How to change the direction of the columns in the Angular Material table?

Tags: angular-material, angular6

Does anyone know how in the table from this example: https://stackblitz.com/angular/dlxbkjqaoba?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Make it so that the columns are directed horizontally, roughly like in the picture:[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use invert the table in an `ngOnInit()` method in the class to give the required data structure and then iterate over the column list in the HTML to give the required columns.  Below is an example:

ts file:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic use of `<table mat-table>`
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'table-basic-example',
  styleUrls: ['table-basic-example.css'],
  templateUrl: 'table-basic-example.html',
})
export class TableBasicExample implements OnInit {
  inputColumns = ['position', 'name', 'weight', 'symbol'];
  inputData = ELEMENT_DATA;

  displayColumns: string[];
  displayData: any[];
  showTable: boolean;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.displayColumns = this.inputData.map(x => x.position.toString());
    this.displayData = this.inputColumns.map(x => this.formatInputRow(x));

    console.log(this.displayColumns);
    console.log(this.displayData);

    this.showTable = true;
  }

  formatInputRow(row) {
    const output = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < this.inputData.length; ++i) {
      output[this.inputData[i].position] = this.inputData[i][row];
    }

    return output;
  }
}

export interface PeriodicElement {
  name: string;
  position: number;
  weight: number;
  symbol: string;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[] = [
  {position: 1, name: 'Hydrogen', weight: 1.0079, symbol: 'H'},
  {position: 2, name: 'Helium', weight: 4.0026, symbol: 'He'},
  {position: 3, name: 'Lithium', weight: 6.941, symbol: 'Li'},
  {position: 4, name: 'Beryllium', weight: 9.0122, symbol: 'Be'},
  {position: 5, name: 'Boron', weight: 10.811, symbol: 'B'},
  {position: 6, name: 'Carbon', weight: 12.0107, symbol: 'C'},
  {position: 7, name: 'Nitrogen', weight: 14.0067, symbol: 'N'},
  {position: 8, name: 'Oxygen', weight: 15.9994, symbol: 'O'},
  {position: 9, name: 'Fluorine', weight: 18.9984, symbol: 'F'},
  {position: 10, name: 'Neon', weight: 20.1797, symbol: 'Ne'},
];


/**  Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

html file:

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="displayData" class="mat-elevation-z8" *ngIf="showTable">

  <!--- Note that these columns can be defined in any order.
        The actual rendered columns are set as a property on the row definition" -->

  <!-- Position Column -->
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of displayColumns">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> {{ column }} </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element[column] }} </td>
  </ng-container>

  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayColumns;"></tr>
</table>



<!-- Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license -->
```

and working stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6dvzc

edited stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h6dvzc-jjqdpk

Comment: Thanks. And how to make the thead of the table was also vertical, as in the picture above?

Comment: @endovitskiiy I am not sure of how to do that.  You can easily add an extra field to the display data with the titles (see edited stackblitz), but to make it order able I am not sure

Comment: Im having trouble with this solution, when the column name is not the same as the interface object key EX: 
`
export interface PeriodicElement {
  visit: number,
  visitDate: string,
  conformity: boolean,
}

inputColumns: string[] = ['Visit Number', 'Visit date', 'Conformity'];
`
, how would be a correct way to solve this?