# Vertical Angular material table with selection

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-table

I need to implement vertical  (columns as rows and vertical data) with selection.
There is some ideas about inverting table (for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043232/how-to-change-the-direction-of-the-columns-in-the-angular-material-table)) but no thoughts about selecting data ("data-columns" in this case) or simply toggle column
Currently I'm using (with standard horizontal table) `SelectionModel` from angulad/cdk and 
`<mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;" (click)="selection.toggle(row)">`

Comment: Selecting data is available with Angular material table so what is the question?

Comment: "select" a column is simple change the class of the "td" a simple `[class.selected]="condition"`, to toogle columns you need change the "displayedColumns" array